# WooCommerce-checkout page login not working

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, checkout

I am trying to design my own checkout page.
I wanted a blank page with no header, no side bars... So I saved a new page template in my child theme folder (code below).

```
<?php
/**
    Template Name: Page with background only
*/
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<style type="text/css">
body { background-color: #cccccc; background-image: url('http://uffekirkegaard.dk/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/bg.jpg'); background-repeat: repeat-y; background-position: top center; background-attachment: scroll; }
#page-content { width: full; margin-left: 100px;margin-right: 100px;margin-top: 30px; }
#page-content p { font-size: 1em; font-family: Georgia; line-height: 1.5em; text-align: justify; }
</style>
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="page-content">
    <?php the_content(); endwhile; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately this code is blocking a feature that already existed in my theme: The login feature.
Now when a visitor click of the login link nothing happened. but if I disactive the page template and click on login the login box will show (check the photos)

[checkout page with blank page template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W95W.png)

[checkout page without blank page template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGWWx.png)

Comment: checkout page link :http://www.reussirlegmat.com/check-out-test/

Comment: jQuery and related js files are not loading for checkout page.

Comment: how can I fix that?

Comment: Did you set the checkout page in "WooCommerce->settings->checkout->Checkout Page" to your custom page?